# Make API call from scrapy when spider_closed

Tags: api, scrapy, webhooks

I have a spider that crawls a few rss feeds and stores the content. When the content is done being stored, I would like to make a call to a webhook URL to perform some actions with the data. I have tried to use spider_closed() but I am unable to get the request to happen.

How can I make an API request on spider_closed()?

```
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.http import Request
from w3lib.html import remove_tags


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://wvsportsnow.com/feed/',
            'https://wvusports.com/rss.aspx'
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True)

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
        spider = super(QuotesSpider, cls).from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
        crawler.signals.connect(spider.spider_closed, signal=signals.spider_closed)
        return spider

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        return scrapy.Request('http://example-webhook.com/', callback=self.parse_req, dont_filter=True)

    def parse_req(self, response):
        self.logger.info(response.url)


    def parse(self, response):
        for post in response.xpath('//channel/item'):
            yield {
                'title' : post.xpath('title//text()').extract_first(),
                'link': post.xpath('link//text()').extract_first(),
                'category': post.xpath('category//text()').extract_first(),
                'pubDate' : post.xpath('pubDate//text()').extract_first(),
                'description' : remove_tags(post.xpath('description//text()').extract_first().strip()),
            }
```